# Polynomial hierarchy

Tags: computational-complexity

While familiarizing myself with polynomial hierarchy, I used this [book](https://books.google.ca/books?hl=en&lr=&id=1fo7_KoFUPsC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=Complexity+theory+de+Ingo+Wegener&ots=8GfUOe879g&sig=ePjx6tnU3GeivrARrWKKofan79s#v=onepage&q=Complexity%20theory%20de%20Ingo%20Wegener&f=false) which is written by Ingo Wegener on page 132. 
Now I'm practicing and I met this exercise :

Let us consider a Boolean formula $\phi$ on the variables $x_1, ...,x_n$. Each $n$ bit vector $\overline x \in \{0,1\}^n$ is a possible assignment to variables and these vectors can be naturally classified in alphabetical order. The ODD-SMALLER-SAT-DECISION  problem is to determine, being given $\phi$, if the smallest assignment $x$ which is satisfactory is such that $x_n = 1$.

How to prove that this problem is part of the complexity class $\Delta_2$ ?

Comment: Why should this question be closed ?

Comment: I guess it is because the author did not show his/her work. Other than that, the post is very good.

Comment: I haven't voted for closing your question, but never mind.

Comment: In fact, if you pay close attention, I said it was a good post, and explained why others vote for closing it.